# "i" variable is undefined in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm just working on the dashboard for my discord.js bot. I have created a variable to select the array from my JSON but the console tells me that the variable is undefined.

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON( "./data/gameactivity.json", function(data) {
    $('#clickable').click(function() {
      /*if ($('#clickable').val() === "1") {
        console.log("yoyoyo");
      }*/
      if ($('#clickable').val() === data.value) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
    var i = data[0];
    console.log(i.value);
  })
});
```

Example of gameactivity.json:

```
{
    "gameactivity": [
        {"text": "ExampleBot is online", "value": "1"},
        {"text": "ExampleBot - !help", "value": "2"},
        {"text": "https://example.de", "value": "3"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: @MarkBaijens He is using `i` within the function.

Comment: Can you share the contents of gameactivity.json with us?

Comment: Did you check the value of `data[0]`? Maybe it `undefined`.

Comment: This is because `data[0] ` is undefined

Comment: @JonWarren 
```{
  "gameactivity": [
    {
      "text": "bot is online",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "text": "bot - !help",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "text": "https://example.de",
      "value": "3"
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: Try replacing `var i = data[0]` with `var i = data.gameactivity[0];`

Comment: @JoelSchwegmann next time, try `console.log(data)` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get value from `data.gameactivity[0]`